# How to create header menu almost like microsoft.com?

Tags: html, css, menu, asp.net-core-mvc, header

In ASP.NET Core MVC, I want a header menu almost as seen on `microsoft.com`, but with some changes. I want all part in large and small screen, except the "All Microsoft" section. I also want a RTL menu.
update:
currently I create this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I want the 3 element in top left remain of their position even after the collapse menu open in small screen. currently I do this with display fix. that Couse the problem logo not exactly in middle of header on small screen.
also when I remove display fix. the header in small screen after open collapsed menu like this:
[image]

also I set "dir=rtl" in body.

I tried this code. I want the menu is like third image not the last one. how to fix this?

```
 <header class="sticky-top">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <button id="collaps-button"  class=" navbar-toggler " type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#mynavbar">
                <svg  width="35" height="35" fill="black" class="bi bi-list" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M2.5 12a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h10a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5z" />
                </svg>
            </button>

            <a id="logo" class="navbar-brand mx-auto "  href=""><img src="~/image/theme/i want app logo.png" style="width:50px;" /> </a>
         
            <div  class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mynavbar">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" id="mynavbar2">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="">Home</a>
                    </li>
                   
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle  " href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">stor</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end text-end " style="background-color:lightgray">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item  " href="#">link 1</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item  " href="#">link 2</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item " href="#">link 3</a></li>
                            </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="">About Us</a>
                    </li>
                    
                </ul>
               
            </div>
           

            <button id="main-search-button" class="nav-item  btn bg-transparent " type="button" style="position:fixed; top: 17px; left: 90px;">
                <svg width="30" height="30" fill="black" class="bi bi-search" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path d="M11.742 10.344a6.5 6.5 0 1 0-1.397 1.398h-.001c.03.04.062.078.098.115l3.85 3.85a1 1 0 0 0 1.415-1.414l-3.85-3.85a1.007 1.007 0 0 0-.115-.1zM12 6.5a5.5 5.5 0 1 1-11 0 5.5 5.5 0 0 1 11 0z" />
                </svg>
            </button>

            <a id="CartLink" class="nav-item mx-1 " href="" style="position:fixed; top: 20px; left: 50px;">
                <svg width="30" height="30" fill="black" class="bi bi-cart" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path d="M0 1.5A.5.5 0 0 1 .5 1H2a.5.5 0 0 1 .485.379L2.89 3H14.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .491.592l-1.5 8A.5.5 0 0 1 13 12H4a.5.5 0 0 1-.491-.408L2.01 3.607 1.61 2H.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zM3.102 4l1.313 7h8.17l1.313-7H3.102zM5 12a2 2 0 1 0 0 4 2 2 0 0 0 0-4zm7 0a2 2 0 1 0 0 4 2 2 0 0 0 0-4zm-7 1a1 1 0 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 0 1 0-2zm7 0a1 1 0 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 0 1 0-2z" />
                </svg>
            </a>

            <a id="SignInLink" href="" class="nav-item " style="position:fixed; top: 20px; left: 10px;">
                <svg  width="30" height="30" fill="black" class="bi bi-person-circle" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path d="M11 6a3 3 0 1 1-6 0 3 3 0 0 1 6 0z" />
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M0 8a8 8 0 1 1 16 0A8 8 0 0 1 0 8zm8-7a7 7 0 0 0-5.468 11.37C3.242 11.226 4.805 10 8 10s4.757 1.225 5.468 2.37A7 7 0 0 0 8 1z" />
                </svg>
            </a>
           

            <form id="form-item" class="d-flex d-none  w-100 mx-1">
                <input class="form-control " type="text" placeholder="Search">
                <button class="btn bg-transparent" type="button">
                    <svg  width="30" height="30" fill="black" class="bi bi-search" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                        <path d="M11.742 10.344a6.5 6.5 0 1 0-1.397 1.398h-.001c.03.04.062.078.098.115l3.85 3.85a1 1 0 0 0 1.415-1.414l-3.85-3.85a1.007 1.007 0 0 0-.115-.1zM12 6.5a5.5 5.5 0 1 1-11 0 5.5 5.5 0 0 1 11 0z" />
                    </svg>
                </button>
                <button class="btn bg-transparent" type="button" id="CancelButton">
                    <svg  width="30" height="30" fill="black" class="bi bi-x-circle" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                        <path d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 1 8 1a7 7 0 0 1 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z" />
                        <path d="M4.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0L8 7.293l2.646-2.647a.5.5 0 0 1 .708.708L8.707 8l2.647 2.646a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708L8 8.707l-2.646 2.647a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708L7.293 8 4.646 5.354a.5.5 0 0 1 0-.708z" />
                    </svg>
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```